Flask and Python interaction
I have created a small Flask application and when I go to run it, no matter what page I select, the output to the browser never changes.   What have I been doing wrong?
from flask import Flask
from perf_api_linux import PerfAPILinux

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/health')
@app.route('/RunTest')
def index():
    return "<p>Ready To go on Home Page<p>"
    # return "<p>Hello,   World!</p>"


def health():
    print ("Health Matters")
    return "<p>Hello from HealthCheck<p>"


def RunTest():
    print("Test Execution Beginning")
    PerfAPILinux.execute()
    return("Test Complete")


Use @app.route to decorate the function that you want to run when you visit that route. Currently, all four of the routes that you've defined are decorating index, so you always visit the home page. Take @app.route('/health') and place it right above the definition of the health function, etc.

A genius you are!   Thank you very much for fantastic hint!   One other question, what would be the process for updating the browser route for runTest?

What's important to understand about decorators (@app.route is a decorator) is that they affect the function that they are immediately above. If you want a browser route to apply to a function that you've defined, you must put the @app.route decorator right above that function.
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    # This page can be visited by navigating to / or /index
    return "<p>Ready To go on Home Page<p>"
    # return "<p>Hello,   World!</p>"

@app.route('/health')
def health():
    # This page can be visited by navigating to /health
    print ("Health Matters")
    return "<p>Hello from HealthCheck<p>"

@app.route('/RunTest')
def RunTest():
    # This function is triggered by navigating to /RunTest
    print("Test Execution Beginning")
    PerfAPILinux.execute()
    return("Test Complete")


Decorators in Python modify the function they are followed by. Multiple decorators on one function will apply all of them; in this case, index is bound to all URLs listed above. I have fixed the code by putting decorators above their function.
from flask import Flask
from perf_api_linux import PerfAPILinux

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "<p>Ready To go on Home Page<p>"
    # return "<p>Hello,   World!</p>"


@app.route('/health')
def health():
    print ("Health Matters")
    return "<p>Hello from HealthCheck<p>"


@app.route('/RunTest')
def RunTest():
    print("Test Execution Beginning")
    PerfAPILinux.execute()
    return("Test Complete")

